# How do I reset the breakers after I shut it off

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

We turned off the main breaker being able to isolate power for one room that needed a new power switch. Now we can’t get it to reset.

Outside is a small box but just contains fuses. No breaker.

I’ve tried the method described on YouTube of turning all breaker switches to off, turning main switch off and on twice and then the rest of the switches one at a time.

Not working.

Comment: What make and model is your main breaker/breaker box?

Comment: Are you saying the circuit breaker is **stuck** and won’t throw back?  Can you add a photo of the circuit breaker panel in question?

Comment: Yes, can you add photos of the breaker panel in question, including the label on the inside of the door?